# Sending ajax request to php fails

Tags: php, ajax, string, cordova, variables

I am sending a string via ajax request to my php file which encodes the string. That works, in the debugger console I recieve the full encoded string.

I want to combine the encoded string with another variable but it dont work it gives me 500 Server error, i tried different solutions but none of them works.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
                  $("#paybutton").click(function() {
                                        var params = "projectpaymentoption=1111&id=",
                                        usernamepay = window.localStorage.getItem("username"),
                                        paymenturl = params + usernamepay;

                                        $.ajax({
                                               type: 'POST',
                                               url: 'http://www.blabla.de/phone/encode.php',
                                               data: $.param({"paymenturl": paymenturl}),
                                               success: function(result) {
                                               window.open('result','_blank','location=no','closebuttoncaption=Zurück');                                                   
                                               console.log(result);
                                               }
                                               });
                                        });
                  });
```

Here my Encode.php:

```
<?php

print_r($_POST); // see full contents of the POST
$user = $_POST['paymenturl'];
print PHP_EOL . $user . PHP_EOL; // see full contents of the $user var
$password = "blabla"; 
$salt = "blabla";

function encode($password,$decrypted,$salt){    
$key = hash('SHA256', $salt . $password, true);    
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,  
MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);   
if (strlen($iv_base64 = rtrim(base64_encode($iv), '=')) != 22) {  
throw new Exception("Encoding failed!");  
}  
$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,   
$decrypted . md5($decrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)); 
return urlencode($iv_base64 . $encrypted);  }

$en = encode($password,$user,$salt);

$output = array "http://pay4mobile.com/Payments/Connect/1111/DE?o={$en}";
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

I want to combine the $en variable with "http://pay4mobile.com/Payments/Connect/1111/DE?o=" and give it back to phonegap inappbrowser which opens but dont work. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is 'array' a typo in your $output= ?

If the output should be a single value in an array, use:

`$output = array("http://pay4mobile.com/Payments/Connect/1111/DE?o={$en}");`

If not, use:

`$output = "http://pay4mobile.com/Payments/Connect/1111/DE?o={$en}";`

Comment: The problem is any solution gives my forward slashes in output url so i cant open it. I need to convert the forward slashes in back slashes in the json encode. JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES dont work but my php version is up 2 date.

Comment: You can urlencode if first, then urldecode it.  $en = urlencode(encode($password,$user,$salt));